# Training a LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train my lstm model but getting 0 as accuracy, precision, recall and f1 score. I downloaded the heart disease dataset from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ronitf/heart-disease-uci). Here's the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, accuracy_score, recall_score, precision_score

heartt = pd.read_csv('heart.csv')

cols_to_norm = ['sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach', 'exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca', 'thal']

heartt[cols_to_norm] = heartt[cols_to_norm].apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))

sex_people = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('sex')
c_p = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('cp')
trest_bps = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('trestbps')
cholestrol = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('chol')
fb_s= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('fbs')
rest_ecg = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('restecg')
thala_ch = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('thalach')
ex_ang = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('exang')
old_peak = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('oldpeak')
slo_pe = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('slope')
c_a = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('ca')
tha_l = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('thal')
ag_e = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('age')

age_buckets = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(ag_e, boundaries=[20,30,40,50,60,70,80])

feat_cols = [sex_people ,c_p, trest_bps ,cholestrol ,fb_s,rest_ecg,thala_ch ,ex_ang, old_peak, slo_pe,c_a, tha_l, age_buckets]

x_data = heartt.drop('target',axis=1)

x_data.info()

labels = heartt['target']

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x_data, labels, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=42)

epochs = 8
n_classes = 1
n_units = 200
n_features = 13
batch_size = 35

xplaceholder= tf.placeholder('float',[None,n_features])
yplaceholder = tf.placeholder('float')

def recurrent_neural_network_model():
    layer ={ 'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_units, n_classes])),'bias': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.split(xplaceholder, n_features, 1)
    print(x)

    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_units)

    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']) + layer['bias']

    return output

def train_neural_network():
    logit = recurrent_neural_network_model()
    logit = tf.reshape(logit, [-1])

    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit, labels=yplaceholder))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        tf.local_variables_initializer().run()

        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            i = 0
            for i in range(int(len(X_train) / batch_size)):

                start = i
                end = i + batch_size

                batch_x = np.array(X_train[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(y_train[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={xplaceholder: batch_x, yplaceholder: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i += batch_size

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)).eval({xplaceholder: np.array(X_test), yplaceholder: np.array(y_test)})
        f1 = f1_score(np.array(y_test), pred, average='macro')
        accuracy=accuracy_score(np.array(y_test), pred)
        recall = recall_score(y_true=np.array(y_test), y_pred= pred)
        precision = precision_score(y_true=np.array(y_test), y_pred=pred)
        print("F1 Score:", f1)
        print("Accuracy Score:",accuracy)
        print("Recall:", recall)
        print("Precision:", precision)


train_neural_network()
```

This is the output that I get:

```
[<tf.Tensor 'split:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:1' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:2' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:3' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:4' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:5' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:6' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:7' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:8' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:9' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:10' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:11' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'split:12' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>]
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-15-5bc4f8465e4c>:8: BasicLSTMCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is deprecated, please use tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell, which supports all the feature this cell currently has. Please replace the existing code with tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(name='basic_lstm_cell').
Epoch 0 completed out of 8 loss: 1.00952459083328
Epoch 1 completed out of 8 loss: 3.3137323707244093e-06
Epoch 2 completed out of 8 loss: 1.6476146610239217e-09
Epoch 3 completed out of 8 loss: 2.08133817797794e-11
Epoch 4 completed out of 8 loss: 1.8306998712108724e-12
Epoch 5 completed out of 8 loss: 4.752560310897734e-13
Epoch 6 completed out of 8 loss: 2.238625324474169e-13
Epoch 7 completed out of 8 loss: 1.4679879558579696e-13
F1 Score: 0.0
Accuracy Score: 0.0
Recall: 0.0
Precision: 0.0
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1137: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no true samples.
  'recall', 'true', average, warn_for)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1137: UndefinedMetricWarning: Recall is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true samples.
  'recall', 'true', average, warn_for)
```

I have confusion as to where I might be wrong here. Why am I getting not proper accuracy, precision, f1 score and recall?

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a look at the dataset, it doesn't look like a problem for LSTM models. LSTMs (and all RNNs in general) are meant to predict continuous outputs - they are the Neural Network-equivalent of time series regression. I know there are cases (such as sentiment analysis using NLP) in which you can apply LSTMs to classification problems, but that doesn't seem to be the case. These data are "atemporal", i.e. each row of the dataset represents a patient, and the sequence of the data doesn't carry any information.

LSTMs are used when you need a model with "memory" of previous states of the data such as a time series. If you want to apply LSTMs I suggest you to change dataset (you can take a look at [this huge list of ML datasets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_datasets_for_machine_learning_research)). Otherwise, if that is the dataset of your interest, to switch to a feed forward Neural Network for classification purpose. For this, you can check [my personal TensorFlow tutorial](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow_Tutorial) on how to do it.

Comment: RNNs can do both regression and classification, its misleading to say that they are meant for continuous outputs (regression).

Comment: lines 3-4:   "I know there are cases (such as sentiment analysis using NLP) in which you can apply LSTMs to classification problems, but that doesn't seem to be the case."

Comment: @Leevo what i want to do is that to predict heart disease from patient's treatment history and health dataset.. if this dataset is not suitable then what kind of heart disease dataset should i use? the ones I found are similar where there are patient's treatment history and are classified into 0 and 1(1 for heart disease positive). also the tutorial where I learn this was to detect credit card fraud. In that dataset too, it was classified into 0 and 1 like the dataset that I used. I think this model will work with the my current dataset but I just couldn't figure out the correct way

Comment: @MLnewb if you're interested in heart desease data then you can stick with it. Just use a different model. I suggest you a classic (i.e. feed forward) Neural Network with two output nodes (for 0-1 classification). You don't need LSTM cells, but normal hidden layers.

For ex., in the tutorial I linked to you I employed a very similar model to classify breast cancers. The output was the same as what you need: two output nodes, classifying breast cancer as Malign or Benign (0-1). Just tweak few parameters, adapting it to your dataset, and you are ready to go.
Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: @Leevo unfortunately I have been given this as an assignment and I'm new to this thing. There maybe some ways to do it if they had given me the assignment I guess. I looked everywhere and this was the closest I got to. They asked me to predict heart disease using RNN(I decided to go with lstm).

Comment: @Leevo I did a program as your tutorial but I got some errors. Can you please look into it. here is the url - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54957053/tensorflow-disease-prediction-using-neural-network